# Icons not aligned correctly in cell (SemanticUI)

Tags: semantic-ui, glyphicons

I'm building a table using Semantic UI, in which I added icons using Semantic's `<i>` tag like this:

```
<i class="audio description icon">
```

The icon shows up in the table, but regrettably the alignment is not that great.
Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean "not aligned" where do you expect it to be?

Comment: If you open the screenshot than you can see that the icon is not in the vertical middle of the cell